# How to get value inside observable collection?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I had use listbox.itemsource as my e.Result.

```
<ListBox Height="476" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,17,0,0" Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="434" Foreground="#FFF5F5F1" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,24,10,0" Name="txtBlockCustName" Text="{Binding CustName, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26" />

                            <TextBlock Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,24,0,0" Name="txtBlockCustEmail" Text="{Binding CustEmail, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="26" />
  </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

how can i get the databinding value?

```
void proxy_FindProfileCompleted(object sender, FindProfileCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
            ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers = this.ListBox1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Customer>;
        }
```

i want to get the customer name and customer email from the observable collection.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do the values not appear in the list box or are you trying to get something else?

Comment: @Josh, I am trying to get the value inside listbox, because it is textblock databinding, so i cant use as normal string name = textblock.text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand if this is what you need, but give it a try:

```
void proxy_FindProfileCompleted(object sender, FindProfileCompletedEventArgs e)
{             
    ListBox1.ItemsSource = e.Result;
    ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers = 
        this.ListBox1.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Customer>;  
    foreach(Customer cust in Customers)
    {
        // You can get cust.CustName
        // and you can get cust.CustEmail
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx for your ans. it is use for to get one value from the observablecollection. what if i want to get whole value for cust.custname only?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by looking at the class `CollectionViewSource`.  This keeps track of the current item (you may have to `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true` on the listbox binding).  You could bind to this instead and pass it around.

If this does not answer your question and I try to come up with a more detailed example.